# Which hash to use with Srtool when upgrading a parachain?

Tags: runtime-upgrade, srtool

In my srtool output:

```
== Compressed
 Version          : [object]
 Metadata         : V14
 Size             : 707.47 KB (724453 bytes)
 Compression      : 81.25%
 setCode          : 0x486de0c2390e07f91cdb69b9eb174dd052e93e1e3d1baa67095ca8e1cc9a0c6b
 authorizeUpgrade : 0xfb2e5fabe6c05d7580582ded90ce2cbf7a2022c5f7e385dff6d615ef84e65cbe
 IPFS             : QmRyZbLd7oPZNvrx6jbMZKJCwTdvhhrPzGvBGjFzWbE9t1
 BLAKE2_256       : 0xea3f3649925bc59d3bbfeddde0fabf2da880d696be15a17a7f410b1b1dd084fd
 Wasm             : ./runtime/target/srtool/release/wbuild/kabocha-runtime/kabocha_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm
```

I would like to upgrade parachain:

The srtool output has the hash already for me:

```
 authorizeUpgrade : 0xfb2e5fabe6c05d7580582ded90ce2cbf7a2022c5f7e385dff6d615ef84e65cbe
```

But if i hash compact compressed file like this:

[image]

As you can see i get the blake_256 hash provided in the output:

```
BLAKE2_256       : 0xea3f3649925bc59d3bbfeddde0fabf2da880d696be15a17a7f410b1b1dd084fd
```

Which one should i use? I am assuming that what has been hashed by srtool is either a differently compressed file, or it is using a different hasher.

Comment: You are confusing 2 hashes, the one of the runtime itself and the one of the call to authorize the upgrade for that specific runtime.

Say the hash of the runtime is `H`.

The `authorizeUpgrade` returned by srtool is the hash of the call:
```
parachainSystem.authorizeUpgrade(H)
```
and not `H` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Why do we introduce srtool?

It's because we want a deterministic result.

Your host, rust-toolchain, or something else could affect the generated bytes.

With srtool, in a fixed docker, a fixed rust toolchain. We can always get the same result.

---

Use blake2-256. https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-parachain/blob/cdc46c6920d7680b0eda1bbec4ebe613c40cba82/.github/workflows/release.yml#L192-L193

Comment: hi there, i know why i am using srtool. But i want to know whats the best hash to use when i enactAuthorize on the parachain. The one srtool provides, or by uploading the file of the compact compressed wasm to polkadot js? i think im going to go with my second approach. But i want to know where the enactAuthorize hash provided by srtool has come from.

Comment: The blake2 hash from srtool should be the same with the uploading-WASM calculated hash from PolkadotApps